# having trouble executing guard switch on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having this error, how can I fix it?

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)

Comment: You should have a look at line 36 of `custom_require.rb`. What file is it trying to load, and does that file exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install [wdm](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm#installation) first:

```
gem install wdm
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to do some quoted searches to find this page, but it finally solved my issue